# Inexpensive Android Oreo device

Tags: android

I was looking at Android Oreo phones and tablets in the store the other day, and they all cost at least $500. Monthly contract payments very much do count.

Is there an inexpensive Oreo device out there?

Comment: What is "inexpensive" to you?

Comment: Probably under $200, but bring the best you got

Comment: Are you looking for phone or tablet or either?

Comment: Either would be fine

Answer (score 1):

[ZTE Tempo Go](https://www.zteusa.com/tempogo) is an [Android Oreo (Go edition)](https://www.android.com/versions/oreo-8-0/go-edition/) phone which is an 80$ android phone with acceptable specs. It has 8 GBs of built-in storage, 854x480 resolution touchscreen and 1 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is Android Oreo, you can buy a [Raspberry Pi 3 B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CD5VC92) (not B+!) for 35$ and install an [unofficial build of Android Oreo](http://konstakang.com/devices/rpi3/LineageOS15.1/) on it, or you can install [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org) on your computer, which costs nothing. Might not be the best option, but definitely the most affordable option.